# Backbone paginator not paginating my collection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-paginator

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/shared_object',
  'backbone_paginate'
], function(_, Backbone, Shared_Object){
   "use strict";
  var myCollection= Backbone.Collection.extend({
      initialize: function(option) {
          Backbone.Pagination.enable(this,{ipp:2,fetchOptions:{add:true}});
      },

   model: Shared_Object,
      baseUrl: function() {
          return location.protocol + '//' + location.host+'/address';
      },

    parse:function(dat){
      return dat.items;
    }
  });
  return new myCollection();
});
```

I have this collection and I am trying to paginate this in such a way that it fetches only 2 items per call. As you can see, I have ipp:2 which sets the per page to 2 items per page. Still, I don't understand why it fetches all the items of my collection. Is there something wrong with my Parse() function?

Comment: This sounds like a server issue and not a Backbone issue. I am not that familiar with the above [library][1]. I use [Backbone Paginator][2], developed by Addyosmani. Anyway can you show us the request to the server via your console? Are the params being passed correctly? Whats happening on your API end?

Comment: Two things to look at: 1.) what params are being sent to the server and is ipp on it? 2.) Check if 'ipp' is indeed being received by the server, and is it doing what it's supposed to, to limit the items sent back to the client.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/backbone-paginator ? which version?

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> This sounds like a server issue and not a Backbone issue.
>
> Two things to look at:
>
> 1. what params are being sent to the server and is ipp on it?
> 2. Check if 'ipp' is indeed being received by the server, and is it doing what it's supposed to, to limit the items sent back to the client.